# How to parse SOAP headers inside an Endpoint method using Springs

Tags: spring, soap

I am using Springs 3. I have a method in an Endpoint class which handles the web service request. The method is annotated with @Action to make it asynchronous. The SOAP request header contains some information (like UUID, Reply Address, etc). I need to be able to access these header information from inside this method.

The Spring WS MessageContext as well as the Apache axis MessageContext seems to be empty, so I am not able to use it inside the method to derive the SOAP header.

Comment: It might be easier to answer this question if you included some of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Action and Reply Address - i am assuming that it is WS-Addressing parameters.
Not sure how you got the MessageContext to be null. I had once was in a similar situation earlier (but was not able to access the MessageContext from the Endpoint method).

I followed the steps mentioned in this website [Access Spring WS MessageContext from anywhere](http://www.ogrigas.eu/spring/2009/11/access-spring-ws-messagecontext-from-anywhere).

Once MessageContext is retrieved (hopefully not null), the said parameters can be easily accessed by something like this

```
SoapMessage sm = (SoapMessage) mc.getRequest();
Iterator<SoapHeaderElement> iter = sm.getEnvelope().getHeader().examineAllHeaderElements();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            SoapHeaderElement she = iter.next();
            log.info("\n"+she.getName().getLocalPart()+ " - "+she.getText());   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use unmarshalling to get the header variables.
Suppose you have a header like this

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <v2:XHeader>
     <v2:name>xxx</v2:srvcName>
     <v2:version>1.0</v2:srvcVersion>
     <v2:sender>yyy</v2:senderApp>
   </v2:XHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
```

and your aim is to get the values **xxx,1.0,yyy** inside your endpoint method of the webservice.For this what you have to do is , Create a class say it's name be **MyHeader.java** so that we will unmarshall the incoming header values to this class.This class will look like

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "XHeader", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "version",
    "sender" 
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "XHeader")
public class MyHeader {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String version;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String sender; 


   public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
   public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

     public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
   public void setVersion(String value) {
        this.version = value;
    }
 public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }
   public void setSnder(String value) {
        this.sender = value;
    }


}
```

here what i did is, we have created a java class and annoted it with

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "XHeader")
```

so that we are telling that the root element of the xml should be **XHeader**.
Similarly created three variables and annoted with

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
```

.Now what to do is inside the endpoint method, you create a jaxbcontext object like

```
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyHeaderType.class);
    SoapMessage requestMessage = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();
    SoapHeader reqheader = requestMessage.getSoapHeader();
    Iterator<SoapHeaderElement> itr = reqheader.examineAllHeaderElements();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                SoapHeaderElement ele = itr.next();

                MyHeaderType headerType=(MyHeaderType)jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(ele.getSource());
                 System.out.println(esbHeaderType.getName());
                 System.out.println(esbHeaderType.getVersion());
                 System.out.println(esbHeaderType.getSender());
            }
```

.and now it will print the values **xxx,1.0,yyy**